# How to test if user can register and is redirected to home page?

Tags: python, django, authentication, testing, redirect

I am writing tests in order to see if a user can register and if successful, is redirected to home page.

views.py:

```
class RegisterPageView(View):
      def get(self, request):
          if request.user.is_authenticated:
              return redirect('/')
          form = RegisterForm()
          return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})   

      def post(self, request):
          form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              username = form.cleaned_data['username']
              password = form.cleaned_data['password']
              re_password = form.cleaned_data['re_password']
              first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
              last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
              email = form.cleaned_data['email']
              try:
                  user =  User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
                  context= {'form': form, 'error':'The username you entered has already been taken. Please try another username.'}
                  return render(request, 'register.html', context)
              except User.DoesNotExist:
                  new_user = User(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email)
                  new_user.set_password(password)
                  new_user.save()
                  return redirect('/')
          return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

I have created a
`class RegisterPageViewtest(TestCase):`

```
def setUp(self):
    self.register_url=reverse('register')
    self.user={
        'username':'username',
        'password':'password',
        'password2':'password',
        'first_name':'first_name',
        'last_name':'last_name',
        'email':'email@gmail.com'
    }
```

with a function:

```
def test_user_can_register(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.register_url,self.user,format='text/html')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)
```

However, when I run tests I get a response in a console:

```
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your `views.py` with the view code?

Comment: As requested, I added my views.py

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [assertRedirects method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) to verify if the desired request is redirected.

> `SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, target_status_code=200, msg_prefix='', fetch_redirect_response=True)`
>
> Asserts that the response returned a status_code redirect status, redirected to expected_url (including any GET data), and that the final page was received with target_status_code.
>
> If your request used the follow argument, the expected_url and target_status_code will be the url and status code for the final point of the redirect chain.
>
> If fetch_redirect_response is False, the final page won’t be loaded. Since the test client can’t fetch external URLs, this is particularly useful if expected_url isn’t part of your Django app.
>
> Scheme is handled correctly when making comparisons between two URLs. If there isn’t any scheme specified in the location where we are redirected to, the original request’s scheme is used. If present, the scheme in expected_url is the one used to make the comparisons to.

Also, you can pass a `follow` key argument to your test client [post method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) which will determine if your request should or should not follow any redirects.

> `post(path, data=None, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT, follow=False, secure=False, **extra)`
>
> Makes a POST request on the provided path and returns a Response object, which is documented below.
>
> The key-value pairs in the data dictionary are used to submit POST data.
>
> If you set follow to True the client will follow any redirects and a redirect_chain attribute will be set in the response object containing tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.

Comment: Should I use both of given answers or choose one?

Comment: @Borybar I believe you should use the one that suits you better, however there is still something odd. Your response is returning 200, which means that it didn't suffered redirects, so can you determine which return statement from the view was used? I could recommend to add a `print()` statement before every return and see which one was printed at the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your time and support. I managed to find a solution, which was a typo .... In `setUp` it should be 're_password':'password' NOT 'password2':'password'.

Answer (score 0):

There was an typo error in `RegisterPageViewTest(TestCase):`

```
self.user={
        'username':'username',
        'password':'password',
        'password2':'password',
        'first_name':'first_name',
        'last_name':'last_name',
        'email':'email@gmail.com'
    }
```

SHOULD BE:

```
self.user={
        'username':'username',
        'password':'password',
        're_password':'password',
        'first_name':'first_name',
        'last_name':'last_name',
        'email':'email@gmail.com'
    }
```